# Android start the same activity but close previous one

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

I am trying to start my activity from the notification and it is working but instead of starting the same activity, another (copy) of my activity gets launched when i exit from it I find another copy of the activity beneath it.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
....
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("item", currentObj);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
....
b.setContentIntent(pIntent);
```

how can I fix this ??

Comment: How activities are launched depends on the back stack and the launch mode. You shold read up on android back stack and manifest file attribute `launchMode` to learn more

Comment: Hi, Have you solved this, Or still there is some issue left ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use TaskStackBuilder and add  its parent

```
  TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
```

and you have add it in the notification

```
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
```

What it does is simple it just says android about the parent of the present class you have opened! This should slove your problem. I hope this is helpful. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can call `finish();` before `b.setContentIntent(pIntent);`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a flag you can set that starts the same activity instead of a new one each time:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("item", currentObj);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: this doesn't start new activity, it opens up old activity if already present.

Answer (score 0):

**You can add this line to your `Activity` inside `manifest` to prevent from loading the same activity multiple times**

```
android:launchMode = "singleInstance"
```

**OR**

**Flag the intent before starting Activity like this**

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```